# How can I make friends with users of this website, no IM or SNS account stuff here?

Tags: discussion, contact

Clumsy as it may be...

As we are doing the FAQ stuff on stackoverflow.com, and I wish to make friends with you guys.  But the user profile does not provide a fixed piece of information about user IM and screen names, like Google Talk, MSN, Facebook or Twitter. How can I make friends with users of this website?

Comment: You should probably first participate for a little longer and read a bit more. You then would have known that these kind of questions belong on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This is not a social website. If a user's profile doesn't include any contact information, they don't want to be contacted.

Comment: [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general) chat room is fairly informal, and not a bad place to better get to know some of the more active members here.

Answer (score 5):

## Join us in chat!

I can **highly recommend** the [MSO Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general)!

But there's [StackOverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), [ServerFault Chat](http://chat.serverfault.com/), [SuperUser Chat](http://chat.superuser.com/), and in fact [Chat for every stack exchange site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)!

The users who want to be social will be found in chat. We're a bit crazy, but we don't bite (too hard ;-)

Comment: Crazy? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Pekka Oy... (:

Comment: @Michael Chat is a veritable *bastion* of sanity. A **bastion**.